# what is default block size in rsync

Tags: rsync

What is the default block size in rsync?

If I execute rsync without providing `--block-size` option then what does it ue for a block size?

I am using rsync on a Linux platform.

Answer (score 5):

- If you specify `--block-size=BLOCKSIZE` on the command line, that block size is used.
- If the file size is less than or equal to 490,000 bytes, then the block size is set to 700 bytes.
- If the the file is larger than 490,000 bytes the block size is set to the square root of the file size (rounded to the a multiple of 8) up to a maximum block size dependent on the protocol version.

  - For protocol version <30, the max block size is 536,870,912 (~536MB), whereas
  - for protocol version >=30 the max block size is 131,072 (~131KB) which is more reasonable.
  - You would reach the 131KB max block size with a 17GB file (131KB squared).

So according to newer version of `rsync`, the block sizes range between 700 bytes to 131KB according to what is defined in the [source code constants](https://git.samba.org/rsync.git/?p=rsync.git&a=search&h=be7af36c517757d7ff9562275ebfc04355613dff&st=grep&s=BLOCK_SIZE).

Answer (score 4):

From the `rsync` manual:

> `-B`, `--block-size=BLOCKSIZE`
>
> This forces the block size used in rsync’s delta-transfer
>          algorithm to a fixed value.  It is normally selected based on
>          the size of each file being updated.  See the technical report
>          for details.

The technical report is available at https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/ although it is quite old and does not go into detail about how the block size is selected, only that "that values of S between 500 and 1000 are quite good for most purposes" (these values are not what actually used in the code, see below).

A couple of comments in the actual [source code](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=generator.c;h=5538a92dd57ddf8671a2404a7308ada73a710f58;hb=HEAD#l600) reveals that the square root of the file size is used as the block size (rounded to a multiple of 8):

```c
/*
 * set (initialize) the size entries in the per-file sum_struct
 * calculating dynamic block and checksum sizes.
 *
 * This is only called from generate_and_send_sums() but is a separate
 * function to encapsulate the logic.
 *
 * The block size is a rounded square root of file length.
 *
 * The checksum size is determined according to:
 *     blocksum_bits = BLOCKSUM_BIAS + 2*log2(file_len) - log2(block_len)
 * provided by Donovan Baarda which gives a probability of rsync
 * algorithm corrupting data and falling back using the whole md4
 * checksums.
 *
 * This might be made one of several selectable heuristics.
 */
static void sum_sizes_sqroot(struct sum_struct *sum, int64 len)
{
```

[...]

```c
        else {
            blength = 0;
            do {
                blength |= c;
                if (len < (int64)blength * blength)
                    blength &= ~c;
                c >>= 1;
            } while (c >= 8);   /* round to multiple of 8 */
            blength = MAX(blength, BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
```

The block size chosen is independent of the type of Unix being used.